# Jordan Canonical Form if all eigenvalues are less than 1

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $|\lambda|<1$ for all eigenvalues of square matrix $A$, then does there exist a matrix $T$ such that $\Vert T^{-1}AT\Vert <1$

Comment: You have either one too many or one too few x's in your inequality.

Comment: is it $\|T^{-1} A T x\| < \|x\|$ ?

Comment: Is $1$ the identity matrix here?

Comment: Is $\|\cdot\|$ a particular norm? If not, is it necessarily an operator norm?

Comment: Corrected once more, just magnitude 1

Comment: @learner $\|\cdot\|$ is not usually used to refer to a determinant

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $\|\cdot\|$ is an operator norm:

The answer is yes. It suffices to note that every matrix is similar to its Jordan form, and that the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{\lambda&1\\&\lambda&1\\ &&\ddots \\ &&&&1\\&&&& \lambda},
\pmatrix{\lambda&1/n\\&\lambda&1/n\\ &&\ddots \\ &&&&1/n\\&&&& \lambda}
$$
are similar.

Comment: Can you go into further detail? How does the above JCF similarity prove it's a true statement?

Comment: By choosing a large enough $n$, we can make the norm of the matrix on the right as close as we'd like to $|\lambda|$.

Comment: I'm assuming the $n$ you're referring to is the dimension of the square matrix A, how is it true if n is as low as 2 or 3?

Comment: No! $n$ can be any integer.  That's the point: we can make $n$ as large as we want.